# How to insert an external HTML code in the email signature?

Tags: html, html-email

My email provider allows the implementation of an HTML email signature, taking advantage of this I use the `<map>` parameter to make the signature interactive and take it to my social networks.

The question is: is it possible for me to pull the `<map>` code from an html file on my server or somewhere else instead of hardcoded in the signature html?

I would like to pull the code from an html file because the image can be changed on the server, however the code will remain the same, so if the client opens old emails the map may no longer make sense.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: It's not possible to request remote HTML from an email.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a security issue, so it is not allowed.

Furthermore, images are generally cached. See for example Apple Mail Privacy Protection, which has even killed php implementations that change the images on a new request (a variation of what you are talking about).

Generally, emails in the past, since they are cached (Gmail, Yahoo, Apple Mail and others do this), will still load even if the original file is no longer hosted or changed.

Make sure you are testing this on mobiles, as many implementations of image maps are too big, and have to be scaled down to fit: which could destroy usability on mobiles.

Comment: Perfect, Nathan!
Thank you for your detailed explanation, it's a shame that there's no way to do what I'd like, but the image map alone already allows for many interesting interactions.

As for mobile devices, it really was a problem when I was testing it, the map was lost because the image was resized, but I found a solution by putting everything inside a table, now the image opens and the map is in the correct place regardless of the size of the Image.

Comment: Taking advantage of your knowledge, can you tell me if, in general, email providers accept this type of email signature well?

So far I haven't had any problems with my customers, apparently the emails are being delivered without going to spam.

Comment: @TyroneHirt In terms of spam? It's much less about content these days and more about your server setup (DKIM, DMARC), how well you clean your list, and most importantly, how engaged your customers are. If they love the emails (open it, click on stuff, spend time there etc.) then that's a strong signal it's wanted and not spam. So an email signature is really quite unimportant in that scheme.